# ScrollView onScroll event

Tags: react-native

react-native: 0.50.3

VIDEO: https://youtu.be/Piz30mH4o1s

I want to hide or show navbar on scroll. When user scrolls down, I change the height of navbar and 'paddingTop' position of content. After that 'onScroll' event triggering several times, even if user didn't scroll.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: onScroll Fires at most once per frame during scrolling. so you need put something to stop calling your function again and again. Put timeout or flag so stop calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

I will show u a similar exemple ı hope it helps: 
I assume that you have header component and mainPage components. In mainPage you can pass scrollY value to the header component with onScroll method like this:

```
            onScroll={Animated.event([
          {
            nativeEvent: {
              contentOffset: {
                y:
                this.refs.header === undefined
                  ? 0
                  : this.refs.header.state.scrollY
              }
            }
          }
        ])}
```

And than in header component, you can interpolate your your scrollY value to change headerHeight or header padding style like this

```
    const headerHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
  outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
  extrapolate: "clamp"
});
```

Than u have to change style your animated.view like this:

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.someStyle, {height: headerHeight}]}></Animated.View>
```

Feel free to ask any question to me.